# Setting up SharePoint 2010 guides

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm looking for some guides on setting up SharePoint Server 2010. The guides should be focused on the actual web interface side of things such as Permissions, Layouts, Team Sites etc.

I have searched high and low for guides and most of them are just "How to install Server 2010". These are useless because the installation is self explanatory.

I'm at the stage where I need to learn the config side of things so I can lay my web structure out the way I want it.

Has anyone got any good resources?

Comment: are you looking for guides on (step-by-step) how to set permissions, how to change the layout, etc. Or are you looking for guides at a more conceptual level (you should setup your permissions like this for these reasons.) The reason I'm confused is that you say "focused on the web interface side of things..." but then say that the installation is self explanatory to you. I would think if installation was self explanatory, then going into a site and changing permissions would be as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this page: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc789336.aspx

It's a great jumping-off point for SharePoint architecture and design planning.